# During which bootstrap phase hook_exit & hook_boot will be invoked?

Tags: hooks, bootstrapping

Project Documentation says.. Both are invoked even for cached page views. hook_boot says

> This hook is run at the beginning of the page request. It is typically
>   used to set up global parameters that are needed later in the request.
>
> Only use this hook if your code must run even for cached page views.
>   This hook is called before the theme, modules, or most include files
>   are loaded into memory. **It happens while Drupal is still in bootstrap
>   mode.**

hook_exit says...

> Perform cleanup tasks.
>
> This hook is run at the end of most regular page requests. It is often
>   used for page logging and specialized cleanup. This hook MUST NOT
>   print anything because by the time it runs the response is already
>   sent to the browser.
>
> Only use this hook if your code must run even for cached page views.
>   If you have code which must run once on all non-cached pages, use
>   hook_init() instead. That is the usual case. If you implement this
>   hook and see an error like 'Call to undefined function', it is likely
>   that you are depending on the presence of a module which has not been
>   loaded yet. **It is not loaded because Drupal is still in bootstrap
>   mode.**

Interested to know during which bootstrap phases hook_boot & hook_exit getting invoked so that it will be helpful in cases where above hooks can be used....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hook_boot is getting invoked during fifth phase which is DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_PAGE_HEADER which set up the page header... This is for non cached pages..

```
/**
 * Invokes hook_boot(), initializes locking system, and sends HTTP headers.
 */
function _drupal_bootstrap_page_header() {
  bootstrap_invoke_all('boot');

  if (!drupal_is_cli()) {
    ob_start();
    drupal_page_header();
  }
}
```

For Cached pages both gets executed at Second Phase of Bootstrap which is DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_PAGE_CACHE with little difference...

```
  // If the skipping of the bootstrap hooks is not enforced, call
  // hook_boot.
  if (variable_get('page_cache_invoke_hooks', TRUE)) {
    bootstrap_invoke_all('boot');
  }
  drupal_serve_page_from_cache($cache);
  // If the skipping of the bootstrap hooks is not enforced, call
  // hook_exit.
  if (variable_get('page_cache_invoke_hooks', TRUE)) {
    bootstrap_invoke_all('exit');
  }
```

what make difference between these hooks is

```
  drupal_serve_page_from_cache($cache);
```

Which tells hook_boot and hook_exit is used before and after page requests for tasks like setup and cleanup respectively..

hook_exit also called in common.inc what makes difference is,  Invoke during DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_PAGE_CACHE phase applies where cached page requests are served..  In common.inc hook_exit is called for non cached pages..

```
function drupal_page_footer() {
  global $user;

  module_invoke_all('exit');

  // Commit the user session, if needed.
  drupal_session_commit();

  if (variable_get('cache', 0) && ($cache = drupal_page_set_cache())) {
    drupal_serve_page_from_cache($cache);
  }
  else {
    ob_flush();
  }

  _registry_check_code(REGISTRY_WRITE_LOOKUP_CACHE);
  drupal_cache_system_paths();
  module_implements_write_cache();
  system_run_automated_cron();
}
```

Above confirms even for non cached requests hook_exit is invoked..